# JQuery append doesn´t work in 1 place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I wrote some JS code and everything is fine but the second append() just wont work and i dont know why, I just copied the Code from above and changed 2 names.

```
<div class="playerrole">
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                    $.post("manager.php",
                    {
                        action: "applyPlayerData",
                        playerNr: Player2
                    },
                    function(data){
                        $('.playerrole:eq(1)').append(data); //This works
                    })
            });
            </script>
        </div>
        <div class="playername">
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                    $.post("manager.php",
                    {
                        action: "getPlayerName",
                        playerNr: Player2
                    },
                    function(data){
                        alert(data); //This does output the right thing
                        $('.playername:eq(1)').append(data); //This does not work, even in the Console
                    })
            });
            </script>
        </div>
```

There arent any erros in the Console and I couldnt find anything that would explain why just this on doesnt work.

Comment: use eq(0), its 0-indexed

Comment: If the alert outputs the correct data, it's probably working, but `.playername:eq(1)` doesn't match an element